# Kivy PyInstaller very large package size in Linux

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller, packaging

I am trying to package a code almost 2kb size for linux using PyIntaller, package size is almost 250mb, according to code there is nothing special is imported. How to reduce this size? i am new to packaging all other codes i tried have same package size, here are my imports.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import math
from math import cos, sin, pi
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
import datetime
```

Comment: Did you install Python with Anaconda?

Comment: no i am using system python3.5

Comment: Could you tell me the output of `pip list`?

Comment: pip list is too long to mention in comment,

Comment: Do you have some libmkl*.so in your /dist folder?

Comment: The fact is, Pyinstaller often puts in unneeded libraries.
I have had the same issue, but as I can't know what .so files you have, the only hint I can give you is: Open a shell in the directory, then start to delete the .so files you don't know e see if the binary runs by typing `./file_name`

Comment: No there is no such type of file.

Comment: You don't have to delete them one by one at first, usually you will recognize groups that have similar names.

It will take about 10 minutes, but once you are done, the package will be correctly sized

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there any simple way to avoid this?

Comment: Well, since Pyinstaller cannot package libraries you didn't install, you could try to run Pyinstaller in another environment where your libraries are restricted to the needed ones.
I will write an answer for that.

Comment: Thank you so much, this conversation was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try running `pyinstaller` in a different virtual environment.

To do so on Linux.

1. Install virtualenv
2. In a shell:

   - Create an environment with `virtualenv env_name` - *This will create
     a "env_name" folder in your home directory*
   - Activate the virtual environment with `source activate env_name`
   - Now you are in an environment whith no installed libraries
   - Install cython with `pip install cython==0.26` - *Latest version is 0.27.3, but kivy 1.10 failed to compile while using that, this could change in the future*
   - Install kivy with `pip install kivy`
   - Install pyinstaller and any other dependance of your project
   - Run pyinstaller with `env_name/bin/pyinstaller script.py` - This is needed since, by running `pyinstaller` you would use the one in your original python installation

This should resonably reduce the amount of unneeded libraries in the package, just make sure you don't forget to install anything

Also, notice i didn't use sudo in the `pip install` commands, that's because you don't need it inside the virtual environment, and using it could compromise the result

Comment: Thank you very very much it worked like charm. file size is reduced to 20mb,, this includes python, kivy docutils etc..